Issue with PUT request in Spring service updating database but not reflecting changes in response
I have a method in my Spring service that is called by the controller to handle a PUT request. Essentially, this method takes the ID of the feedback and the new feedback object to perform a custom query on the database. Instead of using JPA's built-in methods, I need to perform casts for non-native types that I use via extensions for PostgreSQL.
I've observed that the database update works correctly; however, when I test it using Postman, I still see the old row instead of the updated one. When I run the query directly on the database, the returned row is the updated one.
Repository
 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM updateFeedback (:feedback_id, :location, CAST(:feedDate AS timestamp with time zone), :sensCode, :feedValue, :clientCode, CAST (:feedEntity AS text)) AS (feedback_id integer, location geography(PointZ,4326), feed_date timestamp with time zone, sens_code text, feed_value double precision, client_code text, feed_entity text, feed_creation_date timestamp with time zone)" , nativeQuery = true)
    Feedback updateFeedback(@Param("feedback_id") Integer feedback_id, @Param("location") String location, @Param("feedDate") LocalDateTime feedDate, @Param("sensCode") String sensCode, @Param("feedValue") Double feedValue, @Param("clientCode") String clientCode, @Param("feedEntity") String feedEntity);

Controller
@PutMapping(path = "/{id}")
      public @ResponseBody
      Feedback updateFeedback(@Valid @RequestBody Feedback newFeedback, @PathVariable Integer id, HttpServletRequest request) {
        AuthenticationParameters parameters = new AuthenticationParameters(request);
        
        if (newFeedback.getClientCode()==null) newFeedback.setClientCode(parameters.getValue()[3]);
        
        newFeedback.setFeedLocation(newFeedback.toWKBString(newFeedback.getLatitude(), newFeedback.getLongitude(), newFeedback.getAltitude()));
        return service.updateFeedback(newFeedback,id);
      }

Service
public Feedback updateFeedback(Feedback newFeedback, Integer id) {
     return repository.findByFeedbackId(id).map(oldFeedback -> {
         return repository.updateFeedback(newFeedback.getFeedbackId()!=null ? newFeedback.getFeedbackId() : oldFeedback.getFeedbackId(), newFeedback.getFeedLocation()!=null ? newFeedback.getFeedLocation() : oldFeedback.getFeedLocation(), newFeedback.getFeedDate()!=null ? newFeedback.getFeedDate() : oldFeedback.getFeedDate(), newFeedback.getSensCode()!=null ? newFeedback.getSensCode() : oldFeedback.getSensCode(), newFeedback.getFeedValue()!=null ? newFeedback.getFeedValue() : oldFeedback.getFeedValue(), newFeedback.getClientCode()!=null ? newFeedback.getClientCode() : oldFeedback.getClientCode(), newFeedback.getFeedEntity()!=null ? newFeedback.getFeedEntity() : oldFeedback.getFeedEntity());
     })
      .orElseGet(() -> {
        newFeedback.setFeedbackId(id);
        return repository.addFeedback(newFeedback.getFeedLocation(), newFeedback.getFeedDate(), newFeedback.getSensCode(), newFeedback.getFeedValue(), newFeedback.getClientCode(), newFeedback.getFeedEntity());
      });
    }

PostgreSQL function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION iot.updateFeedback(feedbackid integer, loc text, feeddate timestamp with time zone, senscode text, feedvalue double precision, clientcode text, feedentity text)
  RETURNS record
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
DECLARE
  result record;
BEGIN

    WITH replaced_feedback AS (
    UPDATE feedback 
    SET location = loc::geography(PointZ,4326),
        feed_date = feeddate,
        sens_code = senscode,
        feed_value = feedvalue,
        client_code = clientcode,
        feed_entity = feedentity
    WHERE feedback_id = feedbackid
    RETURNING feedback_id, location, feed_date,sens_code,feed_value,client_code, feed_entity, feed_creation_date
    )
    SELECT * INTO result FROM replaced_feedback;
    
    return result;
    
END;
$function$

Could someone please guide me on why the changes aren't reflected when testing with the request?

Because you are updating the database but not refetching. Your code is bypassing JPA so you don't get the benefits of it. So you would need to manually refetch the object from the database.

So, returning the result record is useless? Would the only solution be to perform an additional operation, like a select after the update?

In this case yes but that is all because you are basically bypassing the features that JPA offers. Why are you using it like this and not just update the entity? What you have seems far more complex.

Basically, front-end side, the location it's taken as three coordinates and these are parsed to one codified string. I'm using this solution in order to cast "location" field because on the database it's defined as "geography" type.

You should be able to do that with a custom jpa usertype (or there probably is already one from one of the extended postgres libraries for JPA).

I've already delve into this argument. Looks like there is not support for this Geography type using JPA, expecially with three coordinates. That's why I'm dealing with "location" as a string

As mentioned you can always write your own (mapping a Jav type for this with 3 fields to a single column in postgres). That way you wouldn't need all the complexity you now have and can benefit from just using JPA. Instead of jumping through more loopholes.
